# .NET 6 - Pass JSON in query string

Tags: c#, .net, url

I use .NET 6, and I want to use HttpClient.GetAsync to send a query.
One of the arguments is JSON, and I do not know how to encode it correctly.

Here is the documentation I use:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#query-timeseries-points

I have tried with this method, but I got a BAD REQUEST from the server

```
    public async Task<string> MetricAggregateAsync(string from, string to, string query)
    {
        AddDDApiKey();
        AddDDApplicationKey();

        //var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        //System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encore(query);

        query = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);

        string content = "?from=" + from +"&to=" + to + "&query=" + query;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("v1/query" + content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: don't do that, turn it into a POST and send the json in the body instead

Comment: I don't see anything in that documentation that says it's expecting JSON in its query string. What is the value of `content` before you send the request?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu: OP doesn't have control over this endpoint. You're right that it should be a POST if it needs to receive JSON, but the advice doesn't help here as OP couldn't do anything about it *if* it actually did expect JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you shared (thanks for that!) it seems like this `GET /query` endpoint does not expect a JSON content at all. Try this version of your code:

```cs
public async Task<string> MetricAggregateAsync(string from, string to, string query)
{
    AddDDApiKey();
    AddDDApplicationKey();

    query = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);

    string url = $"v1/query?from={from}&to={to}&query={query}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

---

By the way, there are some tricks you could employ:

1. You could remove those

   ```cs
   AddDDApiKey()
   AddDDApplicationKey()
   ```

   calls in `MetricAggregateAsync` (and all other methods that consume this API) if you configured your `_httpClient` to include some headers in all requests it sends, e.g.:

   ```cs
   _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DD-API-KEY", "TODO");
   _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DD-APPLICATION-KEY", "TODO");
   ```

   This should be done in the same place where that `_httpClient` is instantiated (not in `MetricAggregateAsync`).
2. A safer way to build URL strings would be to replace

   ```cs
   query = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);

   string url = $"v1/query?from={from}&to={to}&query={query}";
   ```

   with

   ```cs
   var urlParameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(""); // Strange way to start, but please bear with it :)
   urlParameters.Add("from",  from);
   urlParameters.Add("to",    to);
   urlParameters.Add("query", query); // Automatically encodes URL, so you don't have to do it manually

   string url = $"v1/query?{urlParameters}";
   ```